# What is the geometric meaning of the variables $r$, $v$ and $\phi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this mapping.
$f: \left[0,\infty \right)\times \left[0,2\pi\right] \times \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}  \right] \mapsto \mathbb R ^{3} $

How do I explain what is the geometric meaning of variables r,v and phi? I dont understand really what means "geometric meaning"?

$\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi \\ v \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} r \cdot \cos v \cdot \cos\phi \\ r\cdot \cos v\cdot \sin\phi \\ r\cdot \sin v \end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Have a look at spherical coordinates

Comment: $\phi$ is called azimuth (in geographical terms, it is the longitude), $v$ is the usual latitude. $r$ is the radius of the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Realize that 
$$(r\cos v\cos\phi)^2+(r\cos v\sin\phi)^2+(r\sin v)^2=r^2$$

So, your map represents a sphere in $\mathbb{R}$. Here, $r$ is the radius of the sphere. $v$ is the angle that vector makes with the $xy$-plane and $\phi$ is the angle in the in the circle that is parallel to the $xy$-plane.

Look at the picture

[image]

Comment: Beware, your figure (although it takes the most usual notations) is confusing because it does not take the same conventions as the ones you use in your explanations (as you stick to the notations of Ana) !

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that the given mapping only represents a sphere when $r$ is fixed. Since $r$ can take any value in $[0,\infty)$, I think the function is really describing the usual transformation from spherical polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

By geometric meaning I think of: a way to graphically represent the points.

I will try to make an analogy...

Your mapping takes three values, $(r, \phi, v)$, from the sets $\left[0,\infty \right),  \left[0,2\pi\right],  \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}  \right]$.

By mapping, it is understood that, for each value of $(r, \phi, v)$, there is a *unique* $(x, y, z)$ correspondence in $ \mathbb R ^{3}$. (see the definition of map: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Map.html)

Suppose that $$r \in \left[0,\infty \right), \phi \in \left[0,2\pi\right],  v \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}  \right]$$

and the map

$$\begin{pmatrix} r \\ \phi \\ v \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r \cdot cosv \cdot cos\phi \\ r\cdot cos\cdot sin\phi \\ r\cdot sinv \end{pmatrix}$$

To make a graphic representation of that mapping, create three axis, each being one of the set.

The first axis is the values of $r \in \left[0,\infty \right)$. It will be a line that begins at a point $0$ and never ends, i.e., goes to $\infty$.

[image]

The second axis is defined by $\phi \in \left[0,2\pi\right]$. It is the angle of a circle:

[image]

Your third axis is the angle of a semicircle. $v \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}  \right]$

[image]

Now, how do we put them together to represent $(x,y,z)$?

Try to make them perpendicular to each other.

Begin with $r$ and choose a value. That is, from the line begining at $0$, "walk" up to $r$. Then, from the point $r$, walk in a circle up to the angle $\phi$ (your distance to the point $0$ will remain equal to $r$).

[image]

Then walk in a semicircle up to the angle $v$.

You have ended in a point $(r, \phi, v)$.

Because of the mapping that takes these three variables, you are "teleported" to a corresponding $(x,y,z)$ location. That teleport is proportional to the mapping and will make you end in the location 
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r \cdot cosv \cdot cos\phi \\ r\cdot cos\cdot sin\phi \\ r\cdot sinv \end{pmatrix}$$

### Edit

This teleport I'm talking about is a translation.